# Automatic checkout with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webautomation

I am trying to get a automatic checkout code for [this](https://www.adidas.co.il/en/checkout#Global-e_International_Checkout) website (you will need to go to [here](https://www.adidas.co.il/en/account) and then add a random item to cart in order to access the checkout page)

I have used Selenium IDE to record and export the process of filling out credit card information and checking out.
The exported code looks as following :

```
    self.driver.get("https://www.adidas.co.il/en/checkout#Global-e_International_Checkout")
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(2)
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardNum").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardNum").send_keys("4444 4444 4444 4444")
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardExpiryMonth").click()
    dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardExpiryMonth")
    dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = '08']").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardExpiryYear").click()
    dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardExpiryYear")
    dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = '2031']").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cvdNumber").click()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cvdNumber").send_keys("111")
    self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnPay").click()
```

When executing on Selenium IDE, it works perfectly and flawlessly, but when executing with PyCharm, I get a "no such frame" error, after the code reaches

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

I have also tried to remove `self.driver.switch_to.frame(2)` but then the code stopped at `self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "cardNum").click()` with a error code of "no such element"

Also, I have attempted to use WebDriverWait, but without success.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: what is "Selenium IDE" ?

Comment: A program you can use to record steps such as clicking and writing, and then can be exported to python, c#, java and more languages. You can find more information about it [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/)

Comment: so effectively a macro recorder...  where are the imports and definiions in the python code ?

Comment: more or less, yes. the imports are under "The exported code looks as following:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will dismiss the cookie button, (you may want to place that into a try/Except block, in case you don't get the 'Accept cookies' popup) go through the process of selecting an item, etc, go to checkout and enter the details, up to cc number - you can continue and fill out the rest of the info. It's using Firefox/geckodriver on Linux, however you should be able to adapt it to your own setup, just observe the imports and the part after defining the browser/driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

# firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1500")
# firefox_options.add_argument("--height=500")
# firefox_options.headless = True

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)

url = 'https://www.adidas.co.il/en'

browser.get(url) 

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='affirm btn btn-primary btn-inline']"))).click()

t.sleep(2)

browser.get('https://www.adidas.co.il/en/GY9136.html')
t.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='42 2/3']"))).click()
t.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='add-to-cart btn btn-primary ready']"))).click()
t.sleep(2)
browser.get('https://www.adidas.co.il/en/checkout#Global-e_International_Checkout')  
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Checkout']")))
t.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='CheckoutData_BillingFirstName']"))).send_keys('Harry')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='CheckoutData_BillingLastName']"))).send_keys('Styles')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='CheckoutData_Email']"))).send_keys('harry@styles.net')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='CheckoutData_BillingAddress1']"))).send_keys('Tel Aviv, Eight street, 245')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='BillingZIP']"))).send_keys('2405918')
city_sel = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='BillingCity']"))))
city_sel.select_by_visible_text('Abirim') 
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='secureWindow']")))
print('switched to checkout frame')
t.sleep(2)
cc_field = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='paymentFrm']//input[@id='cardNum']")))
t.sleep(3)
cc_field.send_keys('234234342234234243')
t.sleep(2)
browser.switch_to.default_content()
print('switched back to main content')
t.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Checkout']")))
t.sleep(2)
pay_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='paymentButtonBox']//button[@id='btnPay']")))
t.sleep(2)
print(pay_button.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
t.sleep(1)
pay_button.click()
print('clicked the pay button')
```

Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/
EDIT: Updated the code, so it will also click the "pay' button.